# clock domain crossing metastability issue?

Tags: cdc

How does meta stability occurs at transistor's level? when data toggles between setup and hold window of flip-flop, is it because transistor will be saturation region?

I have studied transistor working and it's characteristics but couldn't relate to meta stability.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I see that you have the [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed?userid=23279379) badge. Are you sure that your question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO?

Comment: Maybe [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate for your question?